# Connecting to Virtual Directory .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, virtual-directory

I have an app that needs access to a virtual directory in IIS. I created the virtual directory in IIS and given it the correct permissions, I'm attempting to connect to it in my startup.cs like so..

```
app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), 
"Folder")),
                RequestPath = "/Folder",

           });
```

But, when I start the site in IIS im getting this error: The directorty name 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myappfolder\Folder does not exist. 
Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Question does this directory really exist? `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myappfolder\Folder`

Comment: @ngeksyo from what i know about virtual directories they map out to a physical directory, so in a sense, no.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#considerations

Answer (score 2):

UseStaticFiles equal to create an independent virtual directory in middleware tier instead of IIS level so it will never read IIS virtual directory. It is recommended to cancel the virtual directory inside your IIS and just map the path string in  PhysicalFileProvider constructor.

More information about app.UseStaticFiles you can refer to this link:
[app.UseStaticFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#serve-files-outside-of-web-root)

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for. I understand this a little better now thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the virtual folder and select advance settings and see what the physical path is and use that.

Comment: ive tired doing this before hand and i couldn't get permissions correct. The physical folder resides on the web server with a path such as c:\folder\ineedthisone

Comment: You may need to give the user full permissions. Add the IIS APPPOOL\YourAppPoolName to the folder

Comment: What if the AppPool is running under a custom account?

Comment: try using that one, if that does not work give the user everyone full permission if that works than you know that you are using the wrong user. Then remove the everyone try again.